# CSS Code or extension for mobile view of event registration

Tags: css, mobile

I am using civicrm for event registration and have noticed that all the input fields go out of the mobile width.  With contact form 7 I usually set the css fields to max-width: 100% but I can find the css id for the fields in the civicrm.  Does anyone have any help with some css code to get those input fields to stay within the mobile view or is there an extension that would do that for me?  Any help would be great.  The page in question is the following.

http://prama.org/civi/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fevent%2Fregister&reset=1&id=132

Thanks Again